# Convert XPath Filter 2.0 to XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

How to translate this XPath Filter 2.0 (http://www.w3.org/2002/06/xmldsig-filter2) statements:

```
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2002/06/xmldsig-filter2">
    <dsig-xpath:XPath xmlns:dsig-xpath="http://www.w3.org/2002/06/xmldsig-filter2" Filter="intersect">
        here()/ancestor::saml2p:ArtifactResolve[1]
    </dsig-xpath:XPath>
</ds:Transform>

<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2002/06/xmldsig-filter2">
    <dsig-xpath:XPath xmlns:dsig-xpath="http://www.w3.org/2002/06/xmldsig-filter2" Filter="subtract">
        here()/ancestor::ds:Signature[1]
    </dsig-xpath:XPath>
</ds:Transform>
```

to XPath (http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116) transform?